# how to prevent hardcoding of links in wordpress code, but keep permalink

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a function that allows me to show a link in my code in wordpress, by including the post or page id of the link but on the front end the permalink gets displayed?

I found `icl_link_to_element` but that only seems to be for WPML.

I could also add a menu but that seems a bit much just for one link.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> get_permalink()

is not useful for you?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink